# i want to edit my $PATH in Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, flutter

I want install flutter on Mac OS Big Sur, so I add

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

and when I

```
echo $PATH
```

I get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/wissem developement/flutter/bin:/Users/wissem developement/flutter/bin:/Users/wissem developement/flutter/bin:/Users/wissem developement/flutter/bin: developement/flutter/bin
```

How can I edit it to get only the Flutter path?

Comment: Does your username have a space in it? `wissem developement`? That's technically legal, but it's going to make things very complicated for you and break a lot of tools that aren't smart enough to handle it. (Space is a common element separator in Unix.) I would strongly recommend renaming your account to remove the space. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548

Comment: That said, it's not clear what you mean by "only the Flutter path" in this case. Your PATH seems to have flutter several times.

Comment: Warning: changing the account name (as described in the Apple support document) can (/will) cause you to [lose admin rights on the Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328192/lost-access-to-admin-user-account-in-my-mac-book-pro)! If you want to do this, make a spare admin account first, so you can re-grant admin rights to the regular one afterward.

Comment: `pwd` will get the current process's working directory (whatever that happens to be when you run the command), which isn't likely to be a good basis for locating the flutter binaries directory. Where is the actual binaries directory?